# Entity browser not showing image after selecting an entity (Drupal 8)

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using drupal 8 entity browser to select entities/images. I cannot figure out how I can show a thumbnail or rendered image after selecting an entity. Below is an image that only shows the label of the entity after selecting

[image]

[image]

I have already checked the `View` and `Entity Browser` but couldn't not find an option to display the image after selecting

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to Manage Display of your media bundle. You may have disabled the image from Manage Display, you can enable it and update the format to Image / Responsive Image or whatever best suits you. Please check the attached screenshot [image]

Comment: No, I just checked the `media bundle` The image is definitely displayed https://imgur.com/a/gCHNo

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set up a view mode for the media entity, which is showing the image field.

Then, on the node, set the view mode of the media entity field to "rendered entity" and select the view mode previously created for the media entity.